# How do I change display language for Guest account under Windows7?

Tags: windows-7, language, guest-account

I want to change **display language** of menus and etc for *Guest* account. Default computer language should be English.

I've installed 2 language packs and I *can* change language in *Control Panel*. Problem is that Guest account has limited rights and can't change his own *display language*.

How do I do that from admin account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest way I can think of is to  give the guest account admin rights, log in, change language, log out, put guest restrictions back.

There must be a better way, but, I can't think of one off the top of my head without being on a domain and using group policy.

edit... Just tried... If you are using a version of Windows with Group Policy Editor (Windows 7 Professional/Ultimate/Enterprise) follow this:

Click the `Start Orb` and type `MMC`. When `MMC` is up, click `File` > `Add / Remove Snap-in`, Choose `Group Policy Object Editor`. Click `Browse` then click the `Users` Tab and choose `Guest`.

From here, Expand `User Configuration` > `Administrative Templates` > `Control Panel` > `Regional and Language` and you can unrestrict these options for the guest account. Also take a look at `User Configuration` > `Administrative Templates` >`System` > `Locale Services`.

Comment: I removed Guest account from Guests group and added it to Administrators group. It worked.

Comment: @marltu - You may want to ensure you move the Guest OUT of the Administrator group once you have it setup.  Or else you might as well give them YOUR password. :)