# Windows 7 Ultimate Change Display Language

Tags: windows-7, language

I have 2 display languages installed in Windows 7 Ultimate, English and Greek. The display language changed by itself to English and when trying to change it back to Greek, the option is grayed out saying "As a guest user you cannot change the display language", even though I am signed in as an Administrator, I haven't enabled the Guest user and there is no other user whatsoever. Any ideas how can I change the display language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved it is I created a new admin account, which I named Test-Admin. I signed in from Test-Admin, changed the display language and copied the settings from the Administrative tab in Region settings for all users.

Therefore, my original admin account is now in Greek, but it still says that I cannot change the display language cause it thinks I am a guest.

I tried giving simple user rights and then admin rights back again to my original admin account, as stated [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/in-windows-7-my-administrator-account-has-somehow/03bfc548-9584-4d5c-b17f-b8bc71593b66), but no luck. It seems that I have a corrupted User Profile, so I will have to transfer all my files and programs to the new admin account I made and delete the original one.

I state the following just for documentation. This User Profile corruption happened after a Windows update, which also redirected my user to system32\config\systemprofile, but I solved this by following the instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/704749/my-user-redirected-to-system32-config-systemprofile-how-to-solve-it). Unfortunately, there was no restore point available.

Answer (score -1):

I think we can try the following way, first we still need to check whether our guest account is disabled. If the guest account is disabled, we enable it, then we remove it from Guests group and add it to Administrators group.
Then we try to change the display language by guest account.

I give the above way according to the articles:
[How do I change display language for Guest account under Windows7?](https://superuser.com/questions/322410/how-do-i-change-display-language-for-guest-account-under-windows7)

If the above does not work, I suggest we reinstall and change the display language.
The detailed steps we can refer the following articles:

[How to change language windows 7 ultimate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2U1B9FscmwM) (video)

[Install & Change to a New Display Language in Windows 7 Ultimate](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-install-and-change-new-display-language-windows-7-ultimate-enterprise)